# Trying to change a \chapter macro without success

Tags: macros, chapters

I am trying to change the word "Capítulo" (portuguese) for "Chapter" with the commands after `%` but it is not working.

```
\documentclass[ruledheader]{abnt_UFF}

%\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}



\usepackage{epsf}
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig,graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}



\usepackage{scalefnt}



\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}


\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicend{\textbf{fim}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicdo{\textbf{faça}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicwhile{\textbf{enquanto}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfor{\textbf{para}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicif{\textbf{se}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicthen{\textbf{então}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicelse{\textbf{senão}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicreturn{\textbf{devolve}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicfunction{\textbf{função}}

\algrenewtext{EndWhile}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicwhile}
\algrenewtext{EndFor}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfor}
\algrenewtext{EndIf}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicif}
\algrenewtext{EndFunction}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}



\newcommand{\cluster}{\textit{cluster}}
\newcommand{\clusters}{\textit{clusters}}

\floatname{algorithm}{Algoritmo}


\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}


\usepackage{colortbl}


\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}


\hyphenation{
a-de-qua-da-men-te 
di-men-sio-na-men-to 
}

\renewcommand{\ABNTchapterfont}{\bfseries\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{b}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\ABNTsectionfont}{\bfseries\fontfamily{cmr}}


\pagestyle{ruledheader}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\@chapapp}{Chapter}
%\makeatother

%\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter}

\chapter{Introduction}
```

[image]

```
> \chapter=\long macro:
->\if@openright \cleardoublepage \else \clearpage \fi \thispagestyle {\chaptert
 itlepagestyle } \ifthenelse {\boolean {ABNTinpretext}}{\ifthenelse {\boolean {A
BNTaftertoc}}{\setboolean {ABNTinpretext}{false}\ABNTBeginOfTextualPart }{}}{}\
global \@topnum \z@ \@afterindentfalse \secdef \@chapter \@schapter .
l.117 \show\chapter
```

Comment: You could search for the definition of chapter in that class, copy it to your document and make the necessary changes there.

Comment: Have you tried to use \renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chapter} in your preamble? Also, it is better if you attach a fully working example in your question.

Comment: Yes, I tried. Edited.

Comment: What you show isn't helpful. A link to the class along with a minimal example would be best. But one word of advice: The class has been made to fit some requirements, and most likely the word should not be translated, or there is an option to do so.